# questionable shading Rubik cube

Tags: modeling

I finished my cube models now and once I completed the 3 basic shapes and duplicated them around to form the cube I saw how big the round magnets were compared to the real life model. So when I zoomed in, I saw this shading issue. And after I selected the area I want to shrink, the shading got worse and the image texture messed up because of the shape of the faces. I hadn't tested it yet, but I think I could try the edit mode press U and project from view and that I think may fix the texture stretching issue, but I'm still curious how to fix that weird shading that is happening around the circle magnet. I have auto smooth on and I can't use the subdivision modifier because it messed up my model from the beginning.
The first image is how it looks zoomed out. Then I zoom in to show the shading around the magnet. I then show what area I'm selecting, then I show how after I shrink it what it did to the texture and also how the shading is still an issue. I do need to shrink all the magnets down by .8 and then ill be finished.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

This is what the texture is supposed to look like.

[image]

Comment: just select the whole face and unwrap again in order to make it match in the UV Editor? By the way I'm not sure why you need such a high-poly topology

Comment: Thank you for always helping me, I just wanted to say you are very helpful. Unwrapping the texture worked, but after I unwrapped it this showed up https://ibb.co/xMTM6KY, and I tried to dissolve all the faces because I'm sure that is a lot for something this simple but when I did merge all the faces those shading lines appeared coming from some corners https://ibb.co/sKjX0dn, and I couldn't figure out how to fix that without using the subdivide modifier. That thing messes with the bevel edges, and they aren't smooth anymore if I used that.

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem but it may be because of bad topology, make sure that you have a good topology in order to keep your object simple and avoid artefacts, etc, for example try something like that: https://zupimages.net/up/21/26/u606.jpg

Comment: dang ill have to start all over again if i did that. i tried to just join some dots and this is what it did https://ibb.co/QcTGh68

Comment: if it fixes your problem, do it, then dissolve all the vertices we see all along the edges, they are useless (Ctrl X > Dissolve Vertices)

Comment: man, :( I was so happy I finally finished it. But you're right, my problem was because I had an issue getting the circle more rounded in the beginning, so I had to subdivide it so much to get those sharp corners closer together. I think you were the one that told me to use the subdivide modifier, but that really messed everything else up. I'm sure that modifier would really help, I'm just not real sure how the proper way to use it and how to resolve any issues I find after using it. I'm still too new to this, so I'm sure I'm taking the long road to making this thing and making it much harder f

Comment: even if you had to subdivide your circle so much (which you didn't if you use a Subdivision Surface) you didn't need to subdivide so much the rest of the face (the grid we see), you could have kept it lowpoly as it is a completely flat surface. Maybe follow some tutorials on basic modeling to understand all that

Comment: I do watch a lot of tutorials, my YouTube history is loaded with blender stuff. I try to apply what they are doing, but I don't get the same results. And the subdivision surface worked great on the flat surfaces, but it made all the beveled edges sharper when they were smooth, and I think something else also messed up I just undid it once I couldn't use it without the edges going back to smooth.

Comment: mmh, I don't see how Subdivision Surface modifier could make the bevel sharper, I'm talking about Subdivision Surface modifier (that you must not apply btw, if you keep your project within Blender), not Subdivide function. And even if you need to subdivide a surface for a reason or another, don't subdivide when it's useless (the grid wee see)

Comment: this is before i use the modifier https://ibb.co/drXCPWB and this is after i use it https://ibb.co/pdqSN9v.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127168/discussion-between-adlowe07-and-moonboots).

Comment: Well, it's a bit hard to have a discussion on BSE, but I'm not sure to understand what's happening with the shading here, giving your object a Subdivision Surface modifier should not make it look sharper... Also, about the honeycomb pattern, I think I told you to use a Bump or Normal map because it would save topology, creating it for real with Knife Project, as advised, was a good idea, but it will make the topology more complicated so you need to create a Normal map afterwards if you want to keep your object low-poly

Comment: This site kept telling me to move this to the discussion page, i didn't know if that would help, but this is what I sent last night.

Comment: This is before I use the modifier https://ibb.co/drXCPWB and this is after I use it https://ibb.co/pdqSN9v
Also, I'm running this on my Mac laptop and every time I use that modifier the laptop fans are spinning fast and loud.
And I think you were the one that told me to use the modifier to get the honeycomb to have some depth. I wasn't able to do that because the modifier looked bad, so I was told to try the bump, but that didn't even give it depth. It just made the black lines shiny to give the illusion.

Comment: Hello, please try the kind of topology I showed you, keep it as low poly as possible, give your object a Subdivision Surface modifier and don't apply it, it should work fine

Comment: or share your file so that I can check what's the problem: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/3e6bb470cc594961899cc717bba6eae0

Comment: so where is the problem you're pointing out? As I said you could use much less faces. Also use Subdivision Surface in Catmull-Clark mode

Comment: Ok, what if I remove the magnet area and made that all one face again. Can I start over from there, or do you think I might have to build the object all over from the beginning? And ill try the catmull-clark mode, I just avoided it because every tutorial I saw the person also avoided it. I think it was something like cause that mode kinda deformed their objects. I can't remember exactly.

Comment: I've tried a topology, please see my answer (I realize it's not exactly the good shape but you see the direction)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler topology for one of your modules, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and il will get round:

[image]

[image]